# Wordpress Order By Meta Value Date

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm currently trying to order a WP-Query by a Date from the Post Meta which is stored in the 'Y-m-d' Format.

This is currently the WP-Query that i'm using:

```
return new WP_Query(
        array(
            'post_type' => 'dokumente',
            'post__in' => $documentIds,
            'paged' => $paged,
            'offset' => $offset,
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'meta_key' => 'datum',
            'meta_type' => 'DATE',
            'orderby' => 'meta_value_date',
        ));
```

But the order is still not working.
The WP_Query documentation is not helpful to me right now and I'm close to converting the meta value in the database to a 'ymd' format, so that I can use 'order by => 'meta_value_num' although the above code MUST work, according to the documentation.

Hope someone can help.

Greetings

Comment: `'orderby' => 'meta_value_date'` is not a thing. You can not just make up your own stuff, and then expect that to work. Use `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` - that will do alphanumeric comparison by default, which will work fine with the `Y-m-d` format. And remove `'meta_type' => 'DATE'` - _casting_ those date strings into actual DATEs doesn't add any benefit here.

Comment: Just for clarification. The 'meta_value_date' was not made up.
From the Wordpress Documentation:
> When using ‘meta_type’ you can also use ‘meta_value_*’ accordingly. For example, when using DATETIME as ‘meta_type’ you can use ‘meta_value_datetime’ to define order structure.

But your suggestion worked. Many thanks!

Comment: Okay. But still makes little sense to cast to DATE first here, so I would just use normal string sorting.